# Python dateparser fails when timezone is in middle

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to parse a date string using the following code:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse

datestring = 'Thu Jul 25 15:13:16 GMT+06:00 2019'

d = parse(datestring)
print (d)
```

The parsed date is:
`datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 25, 15, 13, 16, tzinfo=tzoffset(None, -21600))`

As you can see, instead of adding 6 hours to GMT, it actually subtracted 6 hours.

What's wrong I'm doing here? Any help on how can I parse datestring in this format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a comment in the source: https://github.com/dateutil/dateutil/blob/cbcc0871792e7eed4a42cc62630a08ec7a78be30/dateutil/parser/_parser.py#L803.

> ```
> # Check for something like GMT+3, or BRST+3. Notice
> # that it doesn't mean "I am 3 hours after GMT", but
> # "my time +3 is GMT". If found, we reverse the
> # logic so that timezone parsing code will get it
> # right.
> ```

Important parts

- Notice that it doesn't mean "I am 3 hours after GMT", but "my time +3 is GMT"
- If found, we reverse the logic so that timezone parsing code will get it right

Last sentence in that comment (and 2nd bullet point above) explains why 6 hours are subtracted. Hence, `Thu Jul 25 15:13:16 GMT+06:00 2019` means `Thu Jul 25 09:13:16 2019 GMT`.

Take a look at http://www.timebie.com/tz/timediff.php?q1=Universal%20Time&q2=GMT%20+6%20Time for more context.

Answer (score 0):

dateutil.parse converts every time into GMT. The input is being read as 15:13:16 in GMT+06:00 time. Naturally, it becomes 15:13:16-06:00 in GMT.

Comment: How can I parse the above date then?

Comment: You are already successfully parsing it, you just need to convert it into required timezone when required.

Comment: I've tried. Converting the date to UTC adds another 6 hours. `d.astimezone(pytz.utc)` produces `datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 25, 21, 13, 16, tzinfo=<UTC>)`

Comment: Also parse method can parse `'2018-06-29 17:08:00.586525+05:00'` string successfully with timezone.